# Race condition detection tools

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, race-condition

I would like to test a big and complex (over 1.3M LOC) server application for race conditions. The application is written in C and C++ and running on a 64 bit Linux. I did some research and came up with some dynamic tools (e.g., Intel inspector, Tsan, Helgrind & DRD) and some static tools (e.g., RELAY, RacerX).

The dynamic tools are supposed to be more accurate (less false positives) and can handle custom synchronization mechanisms, but impose a significant runtime overhead that will trigger the application's timeouts. The problem with the static tools is that it seems mostly academic and not maintained (e.g., RELAY's latest version is from 2010).

Currently I'm thinking to use Tsan and stretch the application's timers to accommodate for the added overhead. Did anyone face similar challenges and have some insights I might have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think this might be a past the line of "opinion-based" questions, but I'll take a shot.

Without understanding anything about the application, it is nearly impossible to say what you might need to consider when using tsan. On a smaller (103k LOC) project that I work on, designed for high throughput network stuff, it's nearly always been sufficient to design tests to exercise various code paths and test them. I've never needed to stretch timers or timeouts. I imagine this might be problematic if you have some hard real-time constraints (I do not). I haven't experienced tsan overhead to be prohibitively large.

One thing I will note is that tsan does not play well with concurrent data structures (such as those provided by [concurrencykit](http://concurrencykit.org) and others). This is because the implementation of these concurrent data structures frequently rely on detection of data races to determine execution behavior.

Consider, for instance, a full ring buffer with two concurrent consumers. The readers will likely be flagged as racing on temporary reads of the front of the ring, because they do. However, the consumers linearize on an atomic comare-and-swap operation to set an incremented, racy-read value to the next index of the ring. If the swap fails, the operation is retried. Therefore, although the reads and writes may race, correctness is guaranteed.

From the perspective of tsan, these aren't considered false positives because they are actual data races. On the other hand, they are false positives for all practical purposes because they don't actually cause any incorrect or undefined behavior. There are ways you can instrument your code to avoid this, but it has been more hassle than it's worth when I've tried it. It depends on how noisy your output is.

Also note that if your application is calling into uninstrumented libraries (libc, openssl, whatever), you will miss potential races. If a race happens with concurrent calls to an uninstrumented library, you will miss the race.

If using tsan, don't forget to use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` (and don't forget to place that *after* any `-Olevel` option). Otherwise you'll be in hell with `addr2line`, or forced to rebuild.

Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with the other utilities you've listed, but since your question seems to be about tsan specifically, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that our existing unit tests are not multi-threaded, so in order to exercise concurrent execution I have to run system integration tests which involve a lot of timers. Luckily though there's no lock-free code, but there are custom lock implementations as well as a custom slab allocator. We'll see how TSan handles that...

You are probably right though, this isn't a well structured question...